# Docker Push Results in an Error

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I'm trying to push an image to a repository and I'm doing this using a Travis CI job as below:

```
after_success:
  - if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" ]; then
      docker login -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL;
      echo "Pushing image $DOCKER_APP_NAME to repository $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL";
      docker push $DOCKER_APP_NAMEUUU;
    fi
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Assume that these variables are resolved correctly, but however the image seems not to be pushed to the remote repository! Here is what I see from the build logs:

```
0.52s$ if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" ]; then docker login -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL; echo "Pushing image $DOCKER_APP_NAME to repository $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL"; docker push $DOCKER_APP_NAMEUUU; fi
Login Succeeded
Pushing image repo.treescale.com/joesan/inland24/plant-simulator to repository 
"docker push" requires exactly 1 argument(s).
See 'docker push --help'.
Usage:  docker push [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG]
Push an image or a repository to a registry
```

So what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty specific, `docker push` requires an argument.

Based on the limited information available, I'd say that `$DOCKER_APP_NAMEUUU` doesn't resolve to any value (did you misspell `$DOCKER_APP_NAME`?